Accessing Outlook Calendar Graph API from background service
I'm working on a web app (SPA and backend) that must constantly access the user's Outlook calendar. The users may come from multiple directories and personal accounts. The app will work 24/7, running the background service and modifying the user's calendar without the user's involvement. So far, I have completed the following:

I created AAD app registration with supported account types "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)."

I set RedirectURI to be my SPA base URL and created a secret.

I implemented authentication in SPA with MSAL (msal-browser). My authorization request looks like this: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite+openid+profile+offline_access&response_type=code&client_id=my_client_id...

After the user successfully authenticates and gives all permissions, his account looks like 

I also retrieved tenantId from the id token (tid claim)

Just to verify that my access_token is valid and permissions set correctly, I successfully requested events from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events At this point, I assume the user has successfully given all the required permissions to my app and my background service can access the user's calendar

I successfully requested access_token with client_credentials flow
curl --location 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId_from_step_5/oauth2/v2.0/token' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--data-urlencode 'client_id=clientId_from_step1' 
--data-urlencode 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' 
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=secret_from_step2' 
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'


I requested user's events with the access_token obtained on the previous step https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/my_test_user@outlook.com/events but got the following error
{
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
}

}
I'm stuck at this point and would appreciate any help or suggestions.

UPDATE:
JWT Token obtained with credential_flow (step 7 from above) from https://login.microsoftonline.com/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/oauth2/v2.0/token misses roles (permissions)

I think all personal accounts share the same tenantId=9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad
My app (outlook-sync-dev) permissions in Azure Portal:


Please check your access token by putting it in jwt.ms

I updated my question with a screenshot. The JWT token misses roles for reasons I don't understand.

@monofilm Is the issue resolved?

@Rukmini It is resolved. I got an answer on another platform https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1792233/accessing-outlook-calendar-graph-api-from-backgrou?page=1&orderby=helpful&comment=answer-1571306
It looks like credential flow is not possible with personal accounts. The solution is to capture the refresh_token during the initial user login and use it in the background service to retrieve the access_token. I was hesitant whether I should put it as an answer here since I haven't tested this approach yet.

@Rukmini of course you can

@Rukmini I added additional details in another answer. It appears to be too long for the comment

Do you want to refresh access token?

Yes, I'm refreshing access token. I can't find any other way for the background service to keep access to the calendar that belongs to the personal account

Do you want to achieve this via Postman?

Of course not since I'm refreshing the access token from the background service. I made a screenshot from postman to demonstrate how the query should look like. In real life, it will be C# code

I would be happy to accept the solution. Unfortunately, none of the answers here is complete. And that would be misleading in my opinion

@monofilm Please post a new question on how to handle refresh token in c# with all the details as the initial requirement about client credential flow error is posted as an answer

@Rukmini perhaps we have a misunderstanding here. I know how to handle refresh tokens, and I do not need any help with that.

Okay what is your exact requirement? @monofilm

@Rukmini, I apologize if I unintentionally made this discussion confusing. I put the exact requirements in the first three sentences of my initial questions. The rest is the description of my failed attempt to implement those requirements. I was lucky to get help on another platform (I shared the link earlier), which made me realize that the whole approach of using "client credentials flow" will not work. I figured out another way that I mentioned in my own answer. I am grateful for your help, but I don't have any more questions unless you know a better way of achieving my requirements.

@monofilm The workaround you mentioned in the answer works and its a good approach and no changed are required and any other requirements/clarifications?

I created a Microsoft Entra multi-tenant application and granted API permission like below:

Generated access token via Client credential flow:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope↵:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials


By using the above access token, I tried to call events API for personal account and got the same error:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/events



Note that: Client credential flow does not support Microsoft personal accounts. Hence you must make use of any user interaction flow to call personal account related APIs that is the user must perform login process.

Hence to resolve the error, make use of Authorization code flow:
Grant delegated API permissions:

Generate auth code:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access
&state=12345

And sign-in with personal account:

Generated access token Authorization code flow:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access
code:Code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms


I am able to successfully call events API:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/events


To do the same JavaScript, refer this MsDoc Acquire a token to call a web API (single-page apps) - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft
Reference:
Exceptions in MSAL Java - Microsoft Authentication Library for Java | Microsoft

This is correct. If anyone is still confused about accessing the Outlook calendar of the personal account, I recommend looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/78749233/875010

Try removing the admin consent requirement.

I think that @Rukmini's answer is correct, but omits some not-obvious details. I wanted to add clarification in the comment, but it is just too long, so I'm adding the answer.
My initial question was about accessing Outlook Calendar (of a personal account) via Graph API from the background service. What we know so far:

We can't use "client credentials flow" since it is not available for personal accounts
We can't use "authorization code flow" since there is no user to interact with in the background service

Therefore, the proposed solution is the following:

The personal account user has to log into the app at least once to give the app permission to access the calendar and user profile. We use "authorization code flow" for that.
When we exchange code for a token, we get not only access_token but also refresh_token. We store refresh_token securely somewhere on the server
When the background service needs to access Graph API (without the user being involved), it exchanges refresh_token for the access_token.

Background service periodically should acquire the new refersh_token since it expires in 90 days, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/refresh-tokens

